# JSP,mysql - How to get and store variable from a fresh query result

Tags: mysql, jsp

i have an insert sql query. It works fine, I just want to get the `p_id` that it will produce and store it as a variable, then I will have another `INSERT` statement then I will put the variable of that ID. Im doing a `System.out.println` and it produce `null`

Here is the query that I will run, and it works fine, it inserts the data in the database. (The ID is auto_incremented so i didn't put that)

`int i = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO logs_pms_t_project (p_name, p_objective) VALUES ('"+p_name+"','"+p_objective+"')");`

My thoughts on how to get the `p_id`

`String p_id= request.getParameter("p_id");`  after the above query

Whereas I can now execute the the another query knowing that I have a variable in the `p_id`

`int j = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO logs_pms_r_budget (budget_cost, p_id) VALUES ('"+p_budget+"','"+p_id+"')");`

Comment: executeUPdate returns the number of affected rows

Comment: Sorry mate, it didnt help me.

Comment: I intended to say executeUpdate only returns the number of affected rows. But if you want the last inserted ID from it then look at the answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
int i = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO logs_pms_t_project (p_name, p_objective) 
        VALUES ('"+p_name+"','"+p_objective+"')",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
int lastInsertedID = -1;
if (rs.next()) {
     lastInsertedID = rs.getInt(1);
     System.out.println("Last Inserted ID = " + lastInsertedID);
}
```

It will return the last inserted ID(Primary key).

**Note:** `ExecuteUpdate` returns the `number of affected rows`.

A single insertion will always affect one row in your table. So the variable `i` contains value `1`. But in order to get the **last inserted primary key value** you need to follow the above code snippet.

Comment: So how can I store the ID to a variable?

Comment: So the last inserted ID will be stored in `lastInsertedID` variable. Please check this @WTFZane

Comment: Hey, why does it have to be `-1`?, the edit before that works. Why does this new is different?

Comment: just an initial value. Suppose for some reasons the insertion failed then you can check whether `lastInsertedID` variable contains `-1` or not. `-1` means the insertion failed.

Comment: Okay, wait I got the msg now in the console. Im just working here about the error in the query it says ` Incorrect integer value: '+lastInsertedId+' for column 'p_id' at row 1`

Comment: what is the data type of `pid`? please post your `create table code` @WTFZane

Comment: It is an int. I tried converting the int to string so that I can use the `'"+p_id"'` It works well in the System.out.println. But when I try to run it said `lastInsertedId cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104495/discussion-between-subrata-dey-pappu-and-wtfzane).

Comment: Please join the chat. Click this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104495/discussion-between-subrata-dey-pappu-and-wtfzane) @WTFZane